# Thread-specific monotonic clock source in the kernel

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel, profiling

Is there a monotonic clock source for use by a kernel module that can be attached to a thread and that will only increase when the associated thread is running?

I am looking for something that will work like the `perf` API, except measure the total amount of CPU time consumed so far in nanoseconds rather than measuring cycles or instructions.

In user space, you have the `clock_gettime` function from `librt` where you can specify the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` as the type of clock to get the behavior described above. Looking at the [source code of `clock_gettime`](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.18/sysdeps_2unix_2clock__gettime_8c_source.html), this function calls another function from the `pthread` library called `__pthread_clock_gettime`.

I am looking for something similar that can be setup inside the Linux kernel from a kernel module and attached to a task, given a pointer to the `task_struct` associated with the task.

Comment: I don't know of any such sub-system in the Linux kernel. I believe you will need to implement your own version using a specific timer (for your architecture) possibly using kprobes to instrument the context switching function.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using ktime_get and the preempt_notifier mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I didn't know about this preempt_notifier mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Performance API gives you access to various hardware events and counters. It has a low and high level API. The PAPI_epc function should fit your needs:

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/docs/db/d93/group__high__api.html#ga2f8766ae458b43d41e57e78b930a4f61